# csv column data value that breaks PHP code

Tags: php, csv

I have a CSV file that has 2 rows like that :

```
11,"HUFFY SPORTS DELAWARE","INC.","HUNTINGTON NATIONAL BANK","DEPT. L-2493","COLUMBUS","OH","","","43260-2493","/\ /\ /\/"
12,"OXFORD GOLF","12564 COLLECTIONS CTR DR","","CHICAGO","IL","","",60693,"","912-526-1100",""
```

I'm reading that file in PHP and populating an array with each data column using the following code :

```
<?php
$values = array();
$csvFileName = "test.csv";
if (($handle = fopen($csvFileName, "r")) !== FALSE) {
            while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
                if(count($data) == 1){
                    $f = fopen('php://temp', 'w');
                    fwrite($f, $data[0]);
                    rewind($f);
                    $data = fgetcsv($f, 1000, ",");
                    fclose($f);
                }  
                for($i=0; $i<sizeof($data); $i++){
                    $values[$i] = $data[$i];
                }
                    echo "<pre>";
                    print_r($values);
                    echo "</pre>";
            }
}
?>
```

so I should get a result like that :

```
Array
(
    [0] => 11
    [1] => HUFFY SPORTS DELAWARE
    [2] => INC.
    [3] => HUNTINGTON NATIONAL BANK
    [4] => DEPT. L-2493
    [5] => COLUMBUS
    [6] => OH
    [7] => 
    [8] => 
    [9] => 43260-2493
    [10] => /\ /\ /\
)

Array
(
    [0] => 12
    [1] => OXFORD GOLF
    [2] => 12564 COLLECTIONS CTR DR
    [3] => 
    [4] => CHICAGO
    [5] => IL
    [6] => 
    [7] => 
    [8] => 60693
    [9] => 
    [10] => 912-526-1100
    [11] => 
)
```

however this string "/\ /\ /\" is breaking my code (sounds like the last double quote is ignored) and I get the first line a column data like the following :

```
Array
(
    [0] => 11,"HUFFY SPORTS DELAWARE","INC.","HUNTINGTON NATIONAL BANK","DEPT. L-2493","COLUMBUS","OH","","","43260-2493","/\ /\ /\""
12
    [1] => OXFORD GOLF""
    [2] => 12564 COLLECTIONS CTR DR""
    [3] => "
    [4] => CHICAGO""
    [5] => IL""
    [6] => "
    [7] => "
    [8] => 60693
    [9] => "
    [10] => 912-526-1100""
    [11] => ""

)
```

Is there a way to fix this please?

Answer (score 0):

Set the `$escape` parameter of the [`fgetcsv()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) function to an empty string unless you are actually escaping `"` with a backslash:

```
fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",", '"', '')
```

Comment: Hi, I tried but I get this : Warning: fgetcsv() [function.fgetcsv]: escape must be character

Comment: Instead of an empty string try using some character that you know is not in your CSV file

Comment: I tried  by putting space like that fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",", '"', ' ')and it gives an empty data in array [0] and correct data in array [1], it is not working.

Comment: You have spaces in your CSV so a space wouldn't work. Try some sort of rare Unicode character, for example: ♥ or ☺

Comment: Well I did this : fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",",'"','£') I'm sure I have no £ sign in my csv but same issue , array 0 is empty , array 1 has data